# Give a new variable value 0 or 1 based on the distance between two words in another variable

Tags: r

I am new to R. In my dataset, I have a variable called Reason . I want to create a new column called Price. If any of the following conditions is met:

- word "Price" and word "High" are both mentioned in Reason and the distance between them is less than 6 words
- word "Price" and word "expensive" are both mentioned in Reason and the distance between them is less than 6 words
  -word "Price" and word "increase" are both mentioned in Reason and the distance between them is less than 6 words
  than Price=1. Otherwise, price=0.

I found the following user defined function to get the distance between 2 words

```
distance <- function(string, term1, term2) {
  words <- strsplit(string, "\\s")[[1]]
  indices <- 1:length(words)
  names(indices) <- words
  abs(indices[term1] - indices[term2])
}
```

but I don't know how to apply it the whole column to get the expected results. I tried the following code but it only give me "logical(0)" as the result.

```
for (j in seq(Survey$Reason))
{
  Survey$Price[[j]]<- distance(Survey$Reason[[j]], " price ", " high ") <=6

}
```

Any help is highly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: What should your output look like? This should be easy with `ifelse()`. You could give us example data with `dput(head(Survey))`, so we can try out possible solutions.

Comment: `Survey$Price <- ifelse(distance(Survey$Reason, " price ", " high ") <= 6 | distance(Survey$Reason, " Price ", " increase ") <=6, 1, 0)` should do it, if I understood your problem right.

Comment: Thank you. I tried your code but it gave me NA value. The example data is as below

Comment: structure(list(Reason = c("Their price are extremely high.", 
"Because my price was increased so much, I wouldn't want anyone else to have to deal with that.", 
"Just because the intial workings were fine, but after we realised it would affect our contract, it left a sour taste in our mouth.", 
"Problems with the repair", "They did not handle my complaint as well I would have liked.", 
"Bad service overall.")), .Names = "Reason", row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")

Comment: Your `distance()` function returns `NA` when used on a string like `"Their price are extremely high."` with terms `price` and `high`.

Comment: Because of the "." to be pre-treated; words separated by spaces lead to term "high.". See my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting from your sample data:

```
survey <- structure(list(Reason = c("Their price are extremely high.", "Because my price was increased so much, I wouldn't want anyone else to have to deal with that.", "Just because the intial workings were fine, but after we realised it would affect our contract, it left a sour taste in our mouth.", "Problems with the repair", "They did not handle my complaint as well I would have liked.", "Bad service overall.")), .Names = "Reason", row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

First, I updated your fonction to remove punctuation and directrly returns your position test

```
distanceOK <- function(string, term1, term2,n=6) {
  words <- strsplit(gsub("[[:punct:]]", "", string), "\\s")[[1]]
  indices <- 1:length(words)
  names(indices) <- words
  dist <- abs(indices[term1] - indices[term2])
  ifelse(is.na(dist)|dist>n,0,1)
}
```

Then we apply:

```
survey$Price <- sapply(survey$Reason, FUN=function(str) distanceOK(str, "price","high"))
```

Comment: Thank you. It works but I have just realized that in my dataset, at the top of Reason column, there are some blank rows. So when I apply your code, it gives all 0 while if applying to the sample only, it works perfectly well. How to fix this please? Thank you very much.

Comment: I have found out how to do it. Thank you.